# What is deferrable in Sequelize foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am learning Sequelize and models' foreign keys, however I don't understand what's the purpose [deferable field](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/deferrable/)

> It will create a foreign key that will check the constraints

I don't understand what's constraints(limitations) here. should I define it? I already viewed the code on official docs but It's no help and can't understand its' usage. Would appreciate if someone help me understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The docs mention:

> A collection of properties related to deferrable constraints. It can
>   be used to make foreign key constraints deferrable and to set the
>   constraints within a transaction. **This is only supported in
>   PostgreSQL.**

So, that's your hint to google for `postgres foreign key deferrable` or similar. The [postgres docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-constraints.html):

> SET CONSTRAINTS sets the behavior of constraint checking within the
>   current transaction. IMMEDIATE constraints are checked at the end of
>   each statement. DEFERRED constraints are not checked until transaction
>   commit. Each constraint has its own IMMEDIATE or DEFERRED mode.
>
> Upon creation, a constraint is given one of three characteristics:
>   DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, or NOT
>   DEFERRABLE. The third class is always IMMEDIATE and is not affected by
>   the SET CONSTRAINTS command. The first two classes start every
>   transaction in the indicated mode, but their behavior can be changed
>   within a transaction by SET CONSTRAINTS.

Unpacking that: deferrable means you can "defer" the checking of foreign key constraints til the end of a transaction. (Transactions, by the way, are basically "groups of queries" that either all succeed, or, if one of them fails, all the others are rolled back too.)

Let's take a contrived example: imagine you have a `blogs` table that has a foreign key that points to a `categories` table. When you insert a new blog post, the category it links to must exist - otherwise that `blogs to categories` foreign key constraint will fail. BUT... if we use the deffered feature, then we could do something like this (in psuedo-code):

```
1. Being a transaction
2. Tell postgres to use deferred foreign key constraints for this transaction
3. Insert a blog that links to the "Hello World" category (which does not yet exist)
3a. (Note this is where Postgres would normally check the foreign key constraint and fail)
4. Insert the "Hello World" Category
5. Commit the transaction
6. Because we're using the DEFERRED feature, the foreign key check 
   will happen now, at the end of the transaction, instead of at 3a, 
   and it will succeed, because "Hello Wolrd" category now exists!
```

To cut a long story short, you should leave out the `deferrable` key (or set it to `false`) unless you know you need it.